# Django ImportError at /admin/ cannot import name 'Session'

Tags: python, django, session, django-models

I get this message in Django after running runserver:

> ImportError at /admin/login/ cannot import name 'Session' Request
>   Method:   POST Request
>   URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/ Django
>   Version:  2.0.5 Exception Type:   ImportError Exception Value:     cannot
>   import name 'Session' Exception
>   Location: C:\HOMEWARE\Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py
>   in get_model_class, line 23 Python
>   Executable:   C:\HOMEWARE\Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64\python.exe Python
>   Version:  3.6.4

This is part of my code in settings.py:

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'AppFinal.apps.AppfinalConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #'AppFinal'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ProjetFinal.urls'
```

I've checked everything, but it seems alright, does anyone knows how to handle this kind of error?

thanks

Comment: looks like your app using a different python version which does not have django installed.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, from the site i can see that Django Version: 2.0.5 is compatible with  Python Version: 3.6.4